# Cannot parse the spec file: A JSONObject text must begin with '{'

Tags: json, ajax, geoserver, mapfish

I know this question has been asked before but i have an implementation specific doubt so i am posting it here.
I am printing the map created using Geoserver with the help of the mapfish plugin and i am getting parse error in the ajax request that i am making.
Here is the code snippet responsible for printing the map and the  error :

```
var spec = {
    "mapTitle":"MyMap",//"DistrictMap",
    "units":"degrees",
    "srs":"EPSG:4326",
    "layout":"A4 portrait",//"A4 Landscape",
    "dpi":300,//300,
    "layers": [
    {
        "type": 'WMS',
        "layers": layers_param,
        "baseURL": 'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wms',
        "format": 'image/jpeg'
     }
    ],
   "pages": [
   {       
        "center": [6, 45.5],
        "scale": 4000000,
        "dpi": 150,
        "geodetic": false,
        "rotation":0,
        "mapTitle":"A custom title",
        "comment":"A custom comment",
        "mapComments":"kkomment"
      }
    ]
};

  var spec_str = JSON.stringify(spec);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/pdf/create.json',
    dataType:'json',
    data:spec_str,        
    success : function(){
      alert('Hello');
    }

  });
```

It throws the  following error in the console:

```
Error while generating PDF:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot parse the spec file: A JSONObject text 
must begin with '{' at character 0: 
at org.mapfish.print.MapPrinter.parseSpec(MapPrinter.java:190)
at.........and some more lines of crap!
```

Update: When i added "contentType" : "application/json" to the request..i got another error stating : INVALID CORS REQUEST

Comment: Please add the actual request sent to the question

Comment: Actual request as in?
I am making the ajax request using $.ajax and passing the url parameter to it!

Comment: as in what is in the request you send - it seems not to be JSON when it arrives

Comment: I am sending the JSON object spec by converting it into string and i am suppose to receive the URL for printing as the response but i am getting the error as stated above!

Comment: but your json spec seems not to start with `{` so we need to see what is actually sent, look in the network tab of your browser's debugger

Comment: It does actually start with '{'  right!?

var spec = { "mapTitle" : "Map",........} 

Or are you referring to something else??
Besides in the network tab of the browser the same error that i have posted is being displayed!!

Comment: Look at the request payload

Comment: The following seems to be my request payload:
{"mapTitle":"MyMap","units":"degrees","srs":"EPSG:4326","layout":"A4 portrait","dpi":300,"layers":[{"type":"WMS","layers":"topp:tasmania_state_boundaries,topp:tasmania_roads","baseURL":"http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wms","format":"image/jpeg"}],"pages":[{"center":[6,45.5],"scale":4000000,"dpi":150,"geodetic":false,"rotation":0,"mapTitle":"A custom title","comment":"A custom comment","mapComments":"kkomment"}]}:

Besides i was wondering why is the colon being added at the end of the json object!